# Creating F2FS volume with specified size on Android

Tags: filesystems, partition, android, f2fs

My smartphone is booted to the TWRP recovery and I'm running the ADB Shell as root on Windows.

I have fully unmounted `/data` with the following command:

```
umount /dev/block/mmcblk0p36
```

Then checked it's size:

```
fsck.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p36
```

Result:

```
Info: sector size = 512
Info: total sectors = 11 583 232 (in 512 bytes)
```

Now, **how can I delete this volume (aka *[filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/157163/hfs-theory-what-else-is-there-to-a-system-other-than-a-root-filesystem/158269#158269)*), and re-create it with a specified size, i.e. 11 583 168 blocks?**
I don't care about the contents of this volume, it's already safe on my computer.

It'd be preferable if it could be done with native Android (Cyanogen v13) binaries, but if the only option is to download and `push` 3rd-party binaries, so be it.

This is related to my other question [How to resize the /data F2FS partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146081/how-to-resize-the-data-f2fs-partition) on Android.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **`mkfs.f2fs`**, part of [f2fs-tools](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jaegeuk/f2fs-tools.git) (just like *fsck.f2fs*).

> Usage: **mkfs.f2fs [options] device [sectors]**
>   [options]:
>     -a heap-based allocation [default:1]
>     -d debug level [default:0]
>     -e [extension list] e.g. "mp3,gif,mov"
>     -l label
>     -o overprovision ratio [default:5]
>     -s # of segments per section [default:1]
>     -z # of sections per zone [default:1]
>     -t 0: nodiscard, 1: discard [default:1]
>     -r reserved_bytes [default:0]
>       (use only device_size-reserved_bytes for filesystem)
>     **sectors: number of sectors.** [default: determined by device size]

(Emphasis mine)

To create a new F2FS filesystem on device `mmcblk0p36` with 11583168 sectors total...

```
mkfs.f2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p36 11583168
```

Do note, however, that invoking fsck.f2fs will still report 11583232 sectors, which is the size of the **device**, not the filesystem. mkfs.f2fs refers to this as *total device sectors* (and simply *total sectors* for the filesystem).

Thanks to [Izzy @ Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/146081/57668#comment188734_146081) for pointing out my confusion on partitions/filesystems and also suggesting the `mkfs.f2fs` command.

Comment: Has anyone come across clear definitions of what the parameters do, and importantly how they affect performance and compatibility of the FS